# HTML elements behind audio tag not displayed

Tags: html, audio

I have the following code:

```html
    <div>text</div>    

    <input id="audio_file" type="file" accept="audio/*" />
    <audio id="audio_player" />

    <div>text</div>
```

However only the div before but not after the audio tag is rendered. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close your [audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) correcty with `<audio></audio>` because *it isn't a self closing tag*.

### Solution

```html
<div>text</div>    

<input id="audio_file" type="file" accept="audio/*" />
<audio id="audio_player"></audio>

<div>text</div>
```

### Explanation

Inside the `audio` tag you could insert a `source`, `track` or append a `text conent`.
The `text content` would be displayed if the browser dosn't support the audio api.

```
<!-- from mdn webdocs -->
<audio controls="controls">
  Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
  <source src="foo.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```